# Build table using Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, join-tables

[image]I have a table that populates data pulled from ACF. It basically adds a PDF of a report if there's one available. I think I got that part figured out, but my code is awfully complicated and I'll like to simplify it with a switch statement or something similar. Also, how do I get the table to display a value of 'x' when there's no PDF file available? It's currently removing the cell and I don't want it to do that. Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="float-left table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Company</th>
        <th scope="col">Annual Report</th>
        <th scope="col">Interim Statement</th>
        <th scope="col">Prospectus</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php if( have_rows( 'recent_documents') ): ?>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </th>


                <?php while( have_rows( 'recent_documents') ): the_row(); ?>

                    <?php if ( have_rows( 'new_document') ): ?>

                        <?php while ( have_rows( 'new_document') ): the_row(); ?>

                            <?php if (strpos(get_sub_field( 'report_type'), "Annual") !==false): ?>
                                <td><a href="<?php the_sub_field('file'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>annual</a>
                                </td>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if (strpos(get_sub_field( 'report_type'), "Interim") !==false): ?>
                                <td><a href="<?php the_sub_field('file'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>interim</a>
                                </td>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if (strpos(get_sub_field( 'report_type'), "Prospectus") !==false): ?>
                                <td><a href="<?php the_sub_field('file'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>Prospectus</a>
                                </td>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>


                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>


            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you just fetch the contents of `recent_documents`, you’ll see that it’s a big multidimensional array with all of your data. I find that much easier to output directly rather than using all the `have_rows` nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am new here too, I can't comment and ask for clarification or give some suggestions, so I'll do that here.

Why do you have nested repeaters `recent_documents` and `new_document`? It appears that `recent_documents` always has only single row, otherwise there would be a mess. But anyway, working with what you have, you could do something like this:

```
<table class="float-left table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Company</th>
        <th scope="col">Annual Report</th>
        <th scope="col">Interim Statement</th>
        <th scope="col">Prospectus</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php if( have_rows( 'recent_documents') ): ?>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </th>

                <?php
                // We get the inner repeater (if it exists)
                $documents = get_field( 'recent_documents' );

                // Create our 'dictionary' array
                $report_types = array( 'Annual', 'Interim', 'Prospectus' );

                // Loop through it. This will always create three cells, even if there are no documents.
                foreach ( $report_types as $key => $report_type ) : ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        $new_document = ! empty( $documents[$key]['new_document'] ) ? $documents[$key]['new_document'][0] : false;

                        if ( ! $new_document 
                             || strpos( $new_document['report_type'], $report_type ) === false 
                             || empty( $new_document['file'] ) ) 
                        {
                            echo 'x';
                            continue;
                        }                        
                        echo '<a href="' . $new_document['file'] . '" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>' . $report_type . '</a>';
                        ?>
                    </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if this doesn't do what you wanted.

Please be aware that `new_documents` have to go in this particular order: `Annual, Interim, Prospectus`, otherwise it would skip documents even if they exist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really like how you've simplified it. I tried it in my theme and it's filling 'x' in all the cells. It doesn't seem to be finding any matching PDFs even though they are there.

Comment: @user22768 Can you try again? I think I made a mistake calling the `recent_documents` repeater as a sub_field.

Comment: No luck. Still filling all cells with 'x'

Comment: @user22768 Ok, I finally managed to test this locally, and found some other bugs. Sorry about that! It should work now.

Comment: Ok. So it now finds the Annual Report but not the other documents. I have an Interim Report that it should have picked up as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @user22768 Can you try to remove/comment the `&& strpos( $documents[$key]['report_type'], $report_type) !== false` line? I am not sure if we really need this anyway.

Comment: @user22768 I commented this line in my code, so you can copy/paste.

Comment: No luck. Also, the returned URL does not open the file. I inspected the code and I noticed it was echoing out just the letter 'h' for the href

Comment: @user22768 That is very inconvenient. On my test project it works well. Perhaps I didn't get your ACF structure properly, or something else has gone wrong. What could very much help me is to do a `var_dump( $documents )` and send me using [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or something similar.

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/1L5j6uTh

Comment: @user22768 Can we please step back and see what is the dump of this: `var_dump( get_field( 'recent_documents' ) )`. I think we are on to something here.

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/4iDAseBS

Comment: @user22768 Thanks, that clears a lot. Give it another try now.

Comment: @user22768 You are welcome! I'd appreciate if you would mark my answer as the answer. :)

Comment: Just did. Sorry, I'm still trying to learn how stack exchange works :-)

Comment: Small edit. I noticed that it only populates the table if I add the documents in this order: annual report, interim statement, prospectus. If I switch up the order nothing shows up at all

Comment: @user22768, I was aware of that. The whole setup of the ACF repeaters and the static content (table heading) depends on the right order of the documents added.